# MuleSoft - using flowVars inside endpoint

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm starting using Mule and have some trivial questions. Here one of them.
Suppose you store the address of a url to invoke later on a process on a property file.
Then you want to use an http endpoint specifying this url.
It works fine, you simply put in the address: ${URL_ADDRESS} and that's it.

Now if your url is calculated and set on a flowVar, why the following code does not work?

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" address="#[flowVars['URL_ADDRESS']]" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

It throws this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Address '#[flowVars['URL_ADDRESS']]' for protocol 'http' should start with http://
```

Why is it checked at compilation time? How can I do to set it at runtime?

Answer (score 4):

The protocol cannot be dynamic. You should change your outbound endpoint to 
 `<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" address="http://#[flowVars['URL_ADDRESS']]" doc:name="HTTP"/>`

Comment: Also note that `#[flowVars.URL_ADDRESS]` or even `#[URL_ADDRESS]` would work too and be more concise.

Comment: Thank you Seba and David, it works like a charm if the URL_ADDRESS is defined in a sub-flow. If I define the URL_ADDRESS variable in another flow of the same application as session variable, the main flow does not recognize it.

Comment: And how are you accessing the variable when stored in the session?

Comment: I check it just by #[sessionVars.URL_ADDRESS]

Answer (score 0):

you should use the flow variables in below format. Either #[FileName] or #[flowVars.FileName]